# beforeDestroy hook for nuxt page component

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I need to emit some events before leaving a particular page. So I'm thinking of using the `beforeDestroy` hook to do this. But it seems not triggering the method.

```
// pages/view.vue

beforeDestroy() {
 this.$alertEvent('finished')
}
```

I'm also using the `keep-alive` directive on the `<nuxt>`

How can I trigger this method effectively?

Comment: have you tried router guards?

Answer (score 3):

for Nuxt 3 you can use `onBeforeUnmount`

```js
onBeforeUnmount(() => {
  alert('the component is destroyed')
})
```

https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-lifecycle.html#onbeforeunmount

Answer (score 1):

i think this should work .
maybe you have problem with this.$alertEvent('finished') so you cannot see the result

```
  beforeDestroy() {
    alert('the component is destroy')
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

If your component wrapped inside  - this is what Nuxt keep-alive directive does, then your component will not be destroyed.

You should use `deactivated` hook.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#deactivated